# Ruby/SDLのSGEのインストールでエラー

Tags: ruby

macOS Sierra(10.12.1)にRuby/SDLを導入しようとしたところ、
http://qiita.com/noanoa07/items/88fefe232dc605720e09
こちらのサイトを参考にさせていただいて、SDLライブラリのインストールはできました。
ですが、どうしても**SGE**のインストールでつまづいてしまいます。
[image: terminal画像一部消しが入っています。]

申し訳ございません。なぜかルーターとの接続がおかしくなっていたようです。
もう一度載せます（長ったらしくなってますがすみません。途中でエラーが起きてもとにかく実行させてます。）。

---

もう一度実行した結果が次です。

```
$ brew install http（中略）
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
elasticsearch@1.7   juju@2.0            lumo                stern
github-keygen       kops                nanomsgxx           swiftformat
google-java-format  libgosu             packetbeat
ib                  libmongoc           qwtpolar
==> Updated Formulae
advancecomp                gjstest                    node-build
afflib                     glog                       noti
agda                       goaccess                   notmuch
aha                        gofabric8                  nss
algernon                   gphoto2                    nuget
android-platform-tools     gradle                     osquery
antigen                    grib-api                   pgcli
arangodb                   gtksourceview3             pgrouting
archi-steam-farm           gupnp-tools                pigz
artifactory                gwt                        prometheus
augeas                     gwyddion                   pugixml
aws-sdk-cpp                haproxy                    pyenv
awscli                     hunspell                   pypy3
bullet                     imagemagick                rbenv ✔
caf                        imapfilter                 ripgrep
ceylon                     infer                      rocksdb
cheat                      internetarchive            ruby ✔
checkstyle                 jasper                     ruby-build ✔
cli53                      javarepl                   sfk
cmark                      jboss-forge                snappystream
crystal-lang               jenkins                    snapraid
davmail                    jpeg-turbo                 snzip
dcraw                      lean-cli                   srclib
docker-compose             libarchive                 supersonic
efl                        libbson                    swiftgen
eject                      libgphoto2                 syncthing
elixirscript               libicns                    tasksh
ffmpeg                     libphonenumber             taylor
flow                       libraw                     tcpreplay
fltk                       libtiff ✔                  terraform
folly                      mackup                     testssl
fwup                       macvim                     the_silver_searcher
fzf                        mg3a                       tippecanoe
galen                      mikutter                   ttfautohint
gflags                     modd                       ttyd
ghc                        mongo-c                    typescript
gibo                       mongodb                    ufraw
git-annex                  mono                       vala
git-cola                   mpv                        vim ✔
git-lfs                    netpbm                     vultr
git-octopus                nghttp2                    yarn
git-series                 nim                        you-get
gitbucket                  ninja                      youtube-dl
gitlab-ci-multi-runner     node                       zplug
==> Renamed Formulae
juju -> juju@1.25
==> Deleted Formulae
polygen

######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: Calling Formula.sha1 is disabled!
Use Formula.sha256 instead.
/Users/matsumurataiki/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/sge.rb:9:in `<class:Sge>'
Please report this bug:
  https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:86:in `odeprecated'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:94:in `odisabled'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/compat/sha1.rb:3:in `sha1'
/Users/matsumurataiki/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/sge.rb:9:in `<class:Sge>'
/Users/matsumurataiki/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/sge.rb:6:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:42:in `load_formula_from_path'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:97:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:153:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:88:in `klass'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:84:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:241:in `factory'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:43:in `block in formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:41:in `map'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:41:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:107:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:94:in `<main>'
taikiMac:~ taiki$ gam updaten --system
-bash: gam: command not found
$ gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
$ gem install rubysdl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
$ gem install rsdl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
$ ruby -r sdl -e 'p [:mixer, SDL.constants.include?(:Mixer)]'
[:mixer, false]
$ ruby -r sdl -e 'p [:ttf, SDL.constants.include?(:TTF)]'
[:ttf, false]
$ ruby -r sdl -e 'p [:sge, SDL.respond_to?(:autoLock)]'
[:sge, false]
$ rsdl -r sdl -e 'SDL.init(SDL::INIT_EVERYTHING); SDL.set_video_mode(640, 480, 16, SDL::SWSURFACE); sleep(1)'
-bash: rsdl: command not found
```

Comment: DNSエラーが出ているようですが……

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Could not resolve host: gist.github.com" というエラーなので、DNSでホスト名の名前解決ができない状態だと思います。
ネットワーク接続が正しいかどうか、プロキシを通さないと外部のネットワークにアクセスできない環境かどうかを確認するのが良いと思います。

Comment: インターネット回線側の問題でした。大事な場を汚してしまったこと、ご容赦ください。